# How to geta value from the map with key as variable?

Tags: groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that consists of:

parameters.groovy

```
    static Map<String, String> doMapping() {
        [
                'a-b-c': '1-2-3',
                'd-e-f': '4-5-6',
                'g-h-i': '7-8-9'
        ]
    }
    return this
```

Jenkinsfile

```
    Map<String, String> myMap = null
    ...
    pipeline {
      parameters {
        string(name: 'param1')
      }
      stages {
        stage('Stage 1', {
          ...
          steps {
            script {
              myMap = load('parameters.groovy').doMapping()
            }
          }
        }
        stage('Stage 2', {
          ...
          steps {
            script {
              String p = ""
              String v = ""
              if (params.PARAM1?.trim()) {
                p = params.PARAM1
                v = myMap.get(p)
                if (v == null) { // Set v to p if not found in the map
                  v = p
                }
                echo "v = ${v}"
                v = myMap.get('d-e-f')
                if (v == null) {
                  v = p
                }
                echo "v = ${v}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Input:**

```
param1 = d-e-f
```

**Output:**

```
[Pipeline] echo
v = d-e-f
[Pipeline] echo
v = 4-5-6
```

Why is a map entry not found when variable is used as the key and is found when hardcoded?

I tried to check for empty spaces but there was none, I checked types of map keys, p, params.PARAM1 and v and they are java.lang.String.

Comment: it should work. so, the problem in type (class) or in value. it's impossible to help you by the log. add some asserts and additional prints to your code before getting value: `assert p instanceof String`, `assert p==p.trim()`, `assert p=='d-e-f'`, `echo "p = '$p'"`

Comment: Also log `p` and log as `p.inspect()`.  Could be the missing `trim()` or a problem with internal types (e.g. GString vs String)